# Specifics on using PCA via SVD ... use data matrix or covariance matrix of data matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

So I want to clarify something: if I want to use SVD to compute PCA of matrix X, do I need to use the SVD on $X$ or $X^TX$. If the former, do I need to square the eigenvalues returned by the SVD? If the latter do I need to take the square root of the eigenvalues by SVD?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the SVD of $X$. The principal components are the right singular vectors of $X$.

What may have led to the confusion is this: the singular values are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $\Sigma\triangleq X^TX$, the sample covariance matrix of $X$. The right singular vectors of $X$ are the same as the eigenvectors of $X^TX$.

Frankly, the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) is not bad here.

Comment: If the former, do I need to square the eigenvalues returned by the SVD? If the latter do I need to take the square root of the eigenvalues by SVD?

Comment: Well, it depends. The singular values of $X$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $X^TX$. Technically, the principle component values are the *un-squared* singular values. But I tend to consider the squared versions as having an "energy" interpretation. So for instance, if I say, "I want the components that take up 99% of the energy of the system", then I'll square the singular values, and find $k$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k \sigma_i^2 \geq 0.99 \sum_{i=1}^{\min\{m,n\}} \sigma_i^2$.